# Karate For loop to get ids based on pattern and then use a delete feature

Tags: karate

I have response from an API call that gives me a list of devices each with an id. Some of these devices are test devices with the id starting with the prefix 'Test' Example Test319244.

I wish to only retrieve those ids with the prefix 'Test', may be in an array and be able to pass them to another feature file which takes the device ID as the parameter to delete it. Basically I want to delete all the testdevices.

Here is the sample response that contains all the device IDs

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "deviceId": "004401784033074000",
            "deviceType": "AVMAP_TMR",
            "disabled": false,
            "metadata": {
                "createdAt": "2020-07-20T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "modifiedAt": "2020-07-20T00:00:00.000+00:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "deviceId": "Test319246",
            "deviceType": "AVMAP_TMR",
            "disabled": false,
            "metadata": {
                "createdAt": "2020-07-21T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "modifiedAt": "2020-07-21T00:00:00.000+00:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "deviceId": "Test319245",
            "deviceType": "AVMAP_TMR",
            "disabled": false,
            "metadata": {
                "createdAt": "2020-07-21T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "modifiedAt": "2020-07-21T00:00:00.000+00:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "deviceId": "Test319244",
            "deviceType": "AVMAP_TMR",
            "disabled": false,
            "metadata": {
                "createdAt": "2020-07-21T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "modifiedAt": "2020-07-21T00:00:00.000+00:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "deviceId": "command-service",
            "deviceType": "service",
            "disabled": false,
            "metadata": {
                "createdAt": "2020-07-20T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "modifiedAt": "2020-07-20T00:00:00.000+00:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "deviceId": "kafka-connect-all",
            "deviceType": "kafka-connect",
            "disabled": false,
            "metadata": {
                "createdAt": "2020-07-20T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "modifiedAt": "2020-07-20T00:00:00.000+00:00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "pagination": {
            "limit": 50,
            "offset": 0,
            "previousOffset": 0,
            "nextOffset": 0,
            "totalCount": 15
        },
        "sortedBy": [
            {
                "field": "deviceId",
                "order": "ASC"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here in the above example I only want to delete the devices with ids - Test319244,Test319245 and Test319246

How can I get an array of ids based on the pattern(Testxxxxxx) and pass that on to another feature file

I need help to define an array of ids like:

```
* def ids = extract the ids based on the pattern
# pass the ids to the delete feature which would send the id one at a time and delete the device.
* def delete = call(delete.feature) ids
```

This is how the delete scenario feature file looks:

```
  Scenario: Delete Device
    # device_registry_url defined in karate-config.js
    Given url device_registry_url
    And path '/device/'+DeviceID
    And header Authorization = authheader
    And request ''
    When method delete
    Then status 200
```

Would this be the right approach or could we do it in a better way? If so, can someone kindly help in how to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `karate.filter()` and then you know what to do:

```
* def fun = function(x){ return x.deviceId.startsWith('Test') }
* def filtered = karate.filter(response.items, fun)
* call read('delete.feature') filtered
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Peter. This is very useful. I was trying out with getting the indexes in the same way but was stuck after that. This is a simple and easier approach. Thank you once again.

Comment: @PeterSmith Can we fetch out the complete json object for which deviceId starts with 'Test'. I have same usecase, please help

Comment: @Yash ask a new question and please keep your example simple